# XPath query: finding all answers to non-required questions

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to find all the answers to non-required questions. This is the xml code:

```
<submittedPoll>
  <pollHead>
    <code>2</code>
  </pollHead>
  <pollBody>
    <topic code="T1">
        <topicHead>
            <title>XML Section</title>
        </topicHead>
        <topicBody>
            <question code="T1Q1" required="true" type="unique">Which encoding did you use?</question>
            <answer code="T1Q1_1">ISO-8859-1</answer>
            <question code="T1Q2" required="true" type="unique">How did you implement blabla?</question>
            <answer code="T1Q2_1">blabla</answer>
            <question code="T1Q3" type="unique">Did you blabla?</question>
            <question code="T1Q4" type="unique">How many times did you blabla?</question>
        </topicBody>
    </topic>
    <topic code="T4">
        <topicHead>
            <title>Other section</title>
        </topicHead>
        <topicBody>
            <question code="T4Q1" type="unique">blabla question?</question>
            <question code="T4Q2" type="unique">blabla other question?</question>
            <question code="T4Q3" required="true" type="multiple">blabla third question?</question>
            <answer code="T4Q3_1">blabla</answer>
            <answer code="T4Q3_2">blablabla</answer>
            <question code="T4Q4" type="unique">blablarly?</question>
            <question code="T4Q5" type="unique">blablanotrly?</question>
            <question code="T4Q6" type="unique">How did you do that?</question>
            <answer code="T4Q6_2">BaseX</answer>
        </topicBody>
    </topic>
  </pollBody>
</submittedPoll>
```

I wrote this XPath query, but it doesn't work as I expect:

```
/submittedPoll/pollBody/topic/topicBody/question[not(@required) or (@required="false")]/following-sibling::answer[starts-with(@code, current()/@code)]
```

This returns T4Q3_1, T4Q3_2 and T4Q6_2. But T4Q3_1 and T4Q3_2 are wrong, since they follow a required question.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I didn't properly understand the `current()` function.

**N.B.:** All the answers "code" attributes begin with the relative question "code" attributes (i.e., question **T4Q3** comes with answers **T4Q3**_1, **T4Q3**_2 etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can simply do:

```
//answer[preceding-sibling::question[1][not(@required) or (@required="false")]]
```

Basically, this says to find answers where the first preceding question is not required.

Comment: You're right! I still have to get in the XPath mood :) Thank you Justin